# Knockout bug? applyBindings doesn't work (Asp.net mvc4 mobile)

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view with three viewmodels: Grower, Branch and GrowerList.

There are two buttons, Grower and Branch. The GrowerList depends upon the selected Branch.

The scenario is as follows:
1. When the user comes to that page, a list of branches (BranchList) is displayed. (Using jQuery mobile's listview to display the list).

1. The user selects a Branch from the BranchList
2. The user can click the "Grower" button to show list of growers and then can select a grower.
3. When the "Grower" button is clicked, a list of growers (GrowerList) are displayed. GrowerList depends upon the selected Branch ID.

Grower, Branch and GrowerList, each has a ViewModel. I am doing the following to display the updated GrowerList:

```
     $("#btnGrower").click(function () {
     ko.applyBindings(new GrowerListModel(), document.getElementById("divGrowerList"));
     });
```

My ViewModel for the GrowerList looks like the following:

```
    function MyGrower(data) {
     this.Id = ko.observable(data.GrowerId);
     this.name = ko.observable(data.GrowerName);
    }

    function MyGrowerListModel() {
     // Data
     var self = this;
     self.growers = ko.observableArray([]);

     //Load initial state from server and populate viewmodel
     $.getJSON("Grower/GetGrowers", function (allData) {
     var mappedUsers = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new MyGrower(item) });
     self.growers(mappedUsers);
     });
    }
```

And, the place where I am binding the values:

```
    <div id="divGrowerList">
           <ul data-bind="foreach: growers" data-role="listview" id="ulGrowerList">
              <li><a data-bind="attr: {id: Id}"><span data-bind="text: name" /></a></li>
          </ul>

    </div>
```

The problem is, although I see through Firebug that correct data is coming from GetGrowers method, nothing is displayed as the GrowerList except for the very first time when the Grower button is clicked. What am I doing wrong? There is no javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

You should only `applyBindings` once for a view model and view ever.  By calling it again, things will not work as you might expect as seen here.

What you should do is apply the bindings *once* on the initial load and call a method that sets the `growers` to the new array of values.  It would be easier to use knockout's bindings to handle the click events than to intermix jquery here.

```html
<button data-bind="click: updateGrowers"></button>
```

```js
function MyGrowerListModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.growers = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.updateGrowers = function () {
        $.getJSON("Grower/GetGrowers", function (allData) {
            var mappedUsers = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new MyGrower(item) });
            self.growers(mappedUsers);
        });
    };

    //Load initial state from server and populate viewmodel
    self.updateGrowers();
}
```

Then, every click on the button will call the `updateGrowers` function on your view model which will in turn, update that array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am very new to knockout and jquery and my javascript skills are limited (talk about the worst possible combination!). Can you suggest how I should structure my ViewModels in this scenario? Thanks again!

Comment: To give you more details, GrowerInfo (button), BranchInfo (button), GrowerList (listview) and BranchList(listview) all come from the database. When a grower is selected in GrowerList, GrowerInfo should be updated by fetching the "GrowerInfo" object from the database again and same happens for the Branch and BranchList. GrowerList depends on the BranchID (selected Branch from BranchList), so when a Branch is selected, both BranchInfo and GrowerList change. I was using 3 viewmodels for GrowerInfo, BranchInfo and GrowerList and in their click events, doing applyBindings for each div. Please help!